# Room Topic Change Helper

Tags: script, chat

When the room topic changes, don't you wish you knew what it used to be before the change? Well now you can!

This script automatically updates room topic change posts with the previous topic so you can compare!

This only updates your local copy of the message, nobody else (without the script) will see the previous topic.

[image]

## [Get Userscript](https://gist.github.com/fredley/b07f98ddb87e37f3a22f)

1. Download the file
2. Drag and Drop onto your Extensions page in Chrome, or install with Greasemonkey in FF